# Customizing "edit user page" in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want customize a user "edit profile" page in Devise. In particular, I want to disallow a user to edit their email address. I can't find that kind of information in their wiki. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

2 quick answers:

1. You could just create your own controller and views to update profile information. I'd assume there might be more fields related to a user profile than just those related to devise.
2. Run `rake routes` to check what routes devise has given you already. You may already have the views to do this, and just not know it.
3. Run `$ rails generate devise:views -v registrations` to copy their views over to your application.

[Devise documenation: configuring views](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-views)